Problem with Keystore file old version
I have an old ethereum keystore file that is not accepted by any modern wallet. I found out that the difference lies in a specific argument: "version": 1, while most wallets use "version": 3. How can I regain access to my wallet?
Additionally, I noticed that my keystore file does not contain an address. However, it does include all other parameters: id, ciphertext, cipherparams, iv, cipher, kdf, and kdfparams.

What is your question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
